# Azure bot framework - Connection open and close

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am new to Azure bot services. I have created a bot and hosted locally. I want to know when the connectivity between user and bot gets closed. 
I actually need this to store chat history to DB that too before connection getting closed. 
I am using Directline API. 
Is bot connection will remains for a long time?
Is there any event triggers before connection close? 
How actally connection between use and bot created and closed?

Comment: `I actually need this to store chat history to DB that too before connection getting closed.` Can you clarify more about your requirement? Do you want to get and trace timestamp/event that indicates user join/leave a specific conversation?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to know when the user closes/exit the bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a directline channel within your own website the following method should work. Essentially you will just send a [backchannel message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-backchannel?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) to your bot when a user closes out of a chat with your bot.

Make sure to define your directline as follows so the connection can be used for backchannel messages

```
botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
    secret: "<secret>"
  });
```

You will want to register an "onunload" method on your html body or div like so:

```
 <body onunload="closeBotChat();">
```

and then within this method you simply send an event from your website to your bot that indicates that the conversation is over

```
 function closeBotChat(){
  botConnection
  .postActivity({
    from: { id: '<user>' },
    value: "chat <conversationId> closed", //send whatever information you need about the conversation here
    type: 'event',
    name: "ConversationUpdate"
  })
  .subscribe(id=> console.log("closed" + id)) // this will likely not be shown unless the botchat is in a modal within the page somewhere
}
```

The following code when used in your bot will be able to hear and process this event:

```
bot.on("event", function(e){
    console.log(util.inspect(e)); // do whatever with the conversation end event here
});
```

Note that you do not have to add anything for an "open connection" event with your bot webchat, as a ConversationUpdate event is sent automatically at the start of a new conversation.

Comment: Thanks alot. Its Working